# Python - use an operator at runtime

Tags: python, function, math, operators, calculator

Is it possible to insert an operation (e.g `*`, `+`) between two variables at runtime?
My solution without doing this is multiple if, elif statements, but I don't think that's the most efficient way to do it.

EDIT: What I meant is I get two integers, and I want to apply an operation on one of them with the other, e.g `x * y`, but I want to change `*` to another operator (maybe they're called functions? Not sure) e.g `-`, `+`,`^` based on input.

Does that make sense? Basically think of it as a calculator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but the [operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module has a lot of operations, e.g. `add` and `mul` (multiply):

```
import operator

var_1 = 2
var_2 = 3

print(operator.add(var_1, var_2))
print(operator.mul(var_1, var_2))
```

will print

```
5
6
```

Answer (score 4):

@AaronHall's is the answer you're looking for, but for completeness, I'd mention you can also use `eval`.

```
var_1 = 2
var_2 = 3
op = '+'
print eval('%s%s%s' % (var_1, op, var_2))
```

However, [eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice), so either don't use it, or use with caution.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the follow-on question, for example, you can subclass int and then implement `__xor__` to exponentiate instead of apply a bitwise or, which is called by the `^` operator:

```
import operator

class MyInt(int):
    def __xor__(self, other):
        return operator.pow(self, other)
```

and then:

```
>>> i = MyInt(2)
>>> i
2
>>> type(i)
<class '__main__.MyInt'>
>>> j = 3
>>> i^j
8
```

Comment: Based on the context, I would guess that OP wanted exponentiation (which is `**`), not xor.

Comment: @Teepeemm and you would be correct, but in order to demonstrate that, I needed a different operator from `**`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes.  I didn't read your answer closely enough to notice you were redefining `^` to be exponentiation.

Answer (score 0):

If your list of operators is small enough you can probably use lambdas.

```
def operator_factory(op):
    if op == '+':
        return lambda x,y: x + y
    elif op == '-':
        return lambda x,y: x - y
    elif op == '*':
        return lambda x,y: x * y
    elif op == '/':
        return lambda x,y: x / y
    elif op == '^':
        return lambda x,y: x ^ y
```

Your if statements can depend on user input. Then you just use this like so:

```
>>> f = operator_factory('+')
>>> f(2,3)
5
```